# Generating python code and adding it to python files

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, code-generation

**What I am trying to do is?
**
I want to generate crud APIs based on the models and add them to the views.py file.
What is the best way to do so?
I know I can just simply append strings in a file but somebody knows some library that can help me do things like these in a more manageable way.
As I can see the same name view exists so I can replace that class only instead of just blindly appending strings

I tried appending strings in the view file but it is not efficient enough for my use case.

Comment: You can use the `ast` package and have full. control of the construct as an option.